# How to copy a file to a destination path according to date modified in linux?

Tags: linux

I have a .files in a directory but I wanted to copy only some files according to date modified(specially month) to a destination path.
How do I do?

Comment: It is quite clear what is being asked in this question. Please be more careful in your downvote judgements. The only reason this question should be closed is if it is a duplicate, which was not the flag raised.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Can you please provide an example of what you would like done? It's a little unclear exactly what you have in mind. For instance, I don't know if you mean you would like to copy only those files from a specific month to one destination, or if you would like to copy all of the files and sort them to different destination paths based on their date modified. An example would be the easiest way to clear this up.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below to search for the files you are looking for and than pass them to execute the action you want, in your case is copy.

```
$ find /path/to/files/ -type f -mtime +25d -exec cp {} /destination/path/ \;
```

> -mtime n[smhdw] If no units are specified, this primary evaluates to true if the difference between the file last modification time and the time find was started, rounded up to the next full 24-hour period, is n 24-hour periods.
>
> If units are specified, this primary evaluates to true if the difference between the file last modification time and the time find was started is exactly n units.
>
> s       second
>
> m       minute (60 seconds)
>
> h       hour (60 minutes)
>
> d       day (24 hours)
>
> w       week (7 days)